# CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object before all references to it are out of scope

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

This warning is extremely annoying, I have read a number of posts suggesting ways around it, but they don't seem to work.

As far as I can see I have catered for all scenarios in the code below yet I still get the warning. I am using VS2010. I am tempted to suppress it but I'd rather fix it if it doesn't get too ugly. Any suggestions?

```
    private LicenseModules CreateDataSource
    {
        get
        {
            // set default result
            LicenseModules result = null;

            try
            {
                result = new LicenseModules();

                // lookup the "Tools" class in the current entry assembly
                var lookup = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name.Equals("Tools", StringComparison.Ordinal));

                // ensure the lookup result is valid
                if (lookup != null)
                {
                    // lookup the Configuration property
                    var prop = lookup.GetProperty("Configuration", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
                    // validate the lookup result
                    if (prop != null)
                    {
                        // read the current Configuration value
                        object value = prop.GetValue(lookup, null);
                        // ensure the read value is valid
                        if (value != null)
                            result = (value as Configuration).Solutions.LicenseModules;
                    }
                }

                // return current result
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    result.Dispose();
                }

                throw;
            }                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
                  if (value != null)
                        result = (value as Configuration).Solutions.LicenseModules;
```

You assign a *new* value to `result` *without* having disposed of the instance you created up here:

```
            result = new LicenseModules();
```

You should create a block and dispose the *old* result value before assigning the new:

```
                  if (value != null) {
                       result.Dipose();
                        result = (value as Configuration).Solutions.LicenseModules;
                  }
```

Comment: Another option is to remove that first assignment and do a null check below the outer `if` block: `return result ?? new LicenseModules();`